# div within a div has different height than parent. Why?

Tags: css

I have a div with `class=main-content` which has height of 100%. I created a popup form which pops out when a link is clicked. Ideally, this form is in a div which makes up the entire page. That way I can make this div have a background color of gray, so it gives the appearance for the user, that he cannot click outside the form.

However the popup has a different height than the parent even though I set the height equal to 100%. Why is this? I thought the height should be in % of the containing block. Thus shouldn't it  be the same height as the parent?

Please see below code and screenshots. I am using bootstrap so that might be a factor, although according to my screenshots, it doesn't appear that anything is overriding my height parameter.

**Edit:** I should mention that I am using SCSS which allows nesting of CSS.

This shows the height of the main-content is set at 100% and that it is indeed the full screen.
[image: Main Content]

This shows the height of the overlay popup is set to 100% but it is not the full screen. Why?
[image: Overlay modal]

Here is my HTML and my CSS:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <!--...the page without the modal goes here -->

   <!--modal starts --> 
    <div id='overlay'>
        <div id = 'modalpopout'>

        </div>
    </div>
   <!--modal ends-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-content{
height:100%;
padding:50px 0 40px 0;
}


#overlay {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%; 
 text-align:center;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color:rgba(105,105,105,0.8);
 #modalpopout {
     width:500px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `position: relative;` to `.main-content`.

Comment: TY sir. After reading some documentation I found that it was the initial containing block. I made the mistake of thinking an initial containing block was the parent. For anyone reading this answer, when you have `position:absolute` the height is relative to the closest parent whose position is absolute, relative or fixed. If there is none, it is the parent. Here is a link with more info and gets more specific: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details

Comment: Exactly :) I was just reading documentation about absolute positioning http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is malformed. Move the #modalpopout CSS **outside** the CSS for #overlay.

```
.main-content{
height:100%;
padding:50px 0 40px 0;
}


#overlay {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%; 
 text-align:center;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color:rgba(105,105,105,0.8);

}


 #modalpopout {
     width:500px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;

     }
```

I can't say if this will fix your specific issue, but this is the proper way to configure CSS.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should mention that I am using Scss which allows for nesting of CSS. Moving it out doesn't have any effects.